# PHP MySQL create duplicate record on unique index strange fail

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Action:** creating table record that is a duplicate on a unique key.

**Good:** The unique key is working because the duplicate record is not created.

**Bad:** The mysqli functions that I am using in PHP are not failing in the way that I expect.

**Meta:** I have some PHP (running 5.3.6) that handles creating new records in a Mysql (5.5.9) table from AJAX POST requests. Authentication and input scrubbing and validation is handled outside of the scope of the code that I am sharing. The respond function also handles printing out the response in a valid format. The table I am inserting into has an auto incrementing id column and a unique name column.

```
// connect to server
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", 'dbpassword', "database");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $response["message"] = "unable to connect to the MySQL server at 'localhost' as 'dbuser' using a password or select the database 'database' because ".mysqli_connect_errno();
    respond($response);
}

// build and run query
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, ?);")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $inputs["name"]);
    $success = $stmt -> execute();
    if ($success) {
        $response["status"] = "success";
        $response["id"] = $mysqli -> insert_id;
        respond($response);
    } else {
        $response["message"] = "failed to insert because ".$stmt -> error;
    }

    $stmt -> close();
} else {
    $response["message"] = "unable to build query because ".$mysqli -> error;
    respond($response);
}

$mysqli -> close();
```

This works as expected when inserting a new unique name but doesn't return anything when attempting to insert a new duplicate name. I expected the

```
$stmt -> execute();
```

to fail so I would return a response explaining the error. This code doesn't do that. The only way I have found to return that the create failed because of a duplicate is to add 2 lines of code before the close statement like this:

```
// connect to server
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", 'dbpassword', "database");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $response["message"] = "unable to connect to the MySQL server at 'localhost' as 'dbuser' using a password or select the database 'database' because ".mysqli_connect_errno();
    respond($response);
}

// build and run query
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, ?);")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $inputs["name"]);
    $success = $stmt -> execute();
    if ($success) {
        $response["status"] = "success";
        $response["id"] = $mysqli -> insert_id;
        respond($response);
    } else {
        $response["message"] = "failed to insert because ".$stmt -> error;
    }

    $stmt -> close();
} else {
    $response["message"] = "unable to build query because ".$mysqli -> error;
    respond($response);
}

$response["message"] = "Duplicate";
respond($response);

$mysqli -> close();
```

The thing I don't understand is when the query runs as expected, the duplicate response is not returned. When the query fails because it is trying to insert a duplicate on the unique key, this returns the duplicate response.

**Question: Why does a successful insert not run the respond function at the end of the code block?**

**Question: Why does a failed insert because of attempting to insert a duplicate on a unique key not throw an exception or fail as I expected?**

I have also tried wrapping the entire thing in a try catch block but it didn't help any because it's not throwing any exceptions. If you could shed any light on this matter I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Question: Why does a successful insert not run the respond function at the end of the code block?*

I assume your `respond` method has an `exit` or `die` in it somewhere that halts execution.

*Question: Why does a failed insert because of attempting to insert a duplicate on a unique key not throw an exception or fail as I expected?*

I think it's to do with the logic in your `if` statements.

If your procedure ever gets into the else statement

```
$response["message"] = "failed to insert because ".$stmt -> error;
```

no response is ever sent (the `respond` function is never called). The reason your second example works is because the code reaches that point every time (because its outside the last `else` statement. If you move a call to `respond` after the line above you might find it returns the message as expected. Full code might look like the following:

```
// connect to server
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", 'dbpassword', "database");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    $response["message"] = "unable to connect to the MySQL server at 'localhost' as 'dbuser' using a password or select the database 'database' because ".mysqli_connect_errno();
    respond($response);
}

// build and run query
if ($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("INSERT INTO `database`.`table` (`id`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, ?);")) {
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $inputs["name"]);
    $success = $stmt -> execute();
    if ($success) {
        $response["status"] = "success";
        $response["id"] = $mysqli -> insert_id;
        respond($response);
    } else {
        $response["message"] = "failed to insert because ".$stmt -> error;
        respond($response); // <-- this is the bit you need
    }

    $stmt -> close();
} else {
    $response["message"] = "unable to build query because ".$mysqli -> error;
    respond($response);
}

$mysqli -> close();
```

Comment: And here I was thinking that I was going crazy. Sure enough I was missing the call to the respond function. Thanks for your help. Sometimes it's best to just walk away and take a look at it again later. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best of us :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to get error information from  `$stmt->errorCode()` and `$stmt->errorInfo()`